# Music Player taking too long to load

Tags: java, android, performance, audio-player

I am new to android development and making a music player app which plays music from external storage, but every time I open the app it takes too much time(15+ secs) to load the music files from the storage.
Is there a way to make it faster like by saving the file location somehow?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ArrayList<File> mySongs = fetchSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                    String[] items = new String[mySongs.size()];
                    for(int i = 0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){
                        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3", "");
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaySong.class);
                            String currentSong = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            intent.putExtra("songList", mySongs);
                            intent.putExtra("currentSong", currentSong);
                            intent.putExtra("position", position);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}
public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs(File file){
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] songs = file.listFiles();
    if(songs != null){
        for(File myFile: songs){
            if (!myFile.isHidden() && myFile.isDirectory()){
                arrayList.addAll(fetchSongs(myFile));
            }
            else if(myFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || myFile.getName().endsWith(".wmv") && !myFile.getName().startsWith(".")
                    && !myFile.getName().endsWith("PM.mp3") && !myFile.getName().endsWith("AM.mp3") &&
                    !myFile.getName().startsWith("Call@") && !myFile.getName().startsWith("AUD")){
                    arrayList.add(myFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to save the name of files and location?

Comment: I don't know how these music apps work, I just want it to load fast, with or without saving files and location